how can a cell be mirrored or flipped in excel
Let's suppose I have cells in Excel with time duration data from a website, copied and pasted in a text file. The format is (hh:mm:ss), like 00:16:30 (equivalent to 0 hours, 16 minutes, and 30 seconds). However, upon opening the text file in Excel, the format switches to (mm:ss:hh), displaying 16:30:00, which Excel reads as (16 hours, 30 minutes, and 0 seconds). How can this problem be fixed or how can the cell be reflected or reversed?

Here is one way you could try:


=TEXTJOIN(":",,SORTBY(TEXTSPLIT(TEXT(A1,"[h]:mm:ss"),":"),-SEQUENCE(,3)))


Updated solution based on OP's edit after the initial answer was posted


=TEXTJOIN(":",,CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(TEXT(A1,"[h]:mm:ss"),":"),3,1,2))


Per OP:

Thank you for your prompt reply and sorry for any inconvenience. I am
sure I am missing something, your solution didn't work for me. the
cells is a custom format 16:30 is readed by excel 4:30:00 PM !!!


Dont see any issues here still, working on my end!



With general value as 0.6875


The given formula still working!!

Posting a screenshot of the file sent by OP over Discussions Chat:



sorry I have updated my problem .. your solution didnt work either, maybe i am missing somthing

Your query was something else, now once an answer was posted you changed the query altogether!, This can also be amended!

@hsawires please check the updated answer!

Thank you for your prompt reply and sorry for any inconvenience. I am sure I am missing something, your solution didn't work for me. the cells is a custom format 16:30 is readed by excel 4:30:00 PM !!!

@hsawires could you make it a general value and show me what is it showing?

it show 0.6875 when convertind to a general value

@hsawires check my updated screenshots it still working on my end, btw what is your local settings, do you use for time [h]:mm:ss or something else, it is completely based on locale

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If the general value is 0.6875 then =TEXT(0.6875;"tt:mm:ss") will show 16:30:00 (tt <=> hh for hours in Swedish locale)

@hsawires here is the Google Sheet link
